# Every time I run uTorrent in Windows 7, I get "Do you want to allow this program to change files on your computer?"

Tags: windows-7, uac, utorrent

Every time I run uTorrent in Windows 7, I get

```
Do you want to allow this program to change files on your computer?
```

I'm new to Windows 7, and this behaviour is annoying me.

Can I make uTorrent a *trusted* application or something?

Comment: I don't have this problem... Do you have it set to download or seed any files to/from a protected location like "C:\Program Files\" or "C:\Windows"?

Comment: @TuxRug I don't think so. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid "evil" programs to be able to whitelist themselves, and have free reign from there on, I believe disabling the UAC for individual applications is not supported by Windows.

Robinson Zhang shows a way to achieve this by abusing the Task Scheduler [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/6cfaab82-da82-4ff9-aa61-416f6134c34d).

Comment: Wow, they still have UAC set so that you have to give the system permission to run Photoshop every single time? I don't care what their marketing strategy is, a warning that cries wolf for the program you've run every day for the past year is a warning that gets completely ignored when there is actually danger. Microsoft is a idiot. `</rant>`

Comment: @msw - It would be "an idiot" and it is not Microsoft's fault. Application developers should be updating their software to fit within the standards of the new security measures - I mean, it has been around since Vista. Also, Photoshop and uTorrent both do not prompt me on launch on Windows 7 or Vista, so I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: @MarkM: Isn't stupid I feeling? I see that you aren't aren't up on your Dickens, Norman, and probably not Carroll; there's glory for you!

Comment: @msw - Grammar from previous eras aside, you shouldn't be seeing that pop up regularly. It is only triggered if something is trying to write to a protected area or run something reserved for an administrator. In your profile it said you worked on sh, so I'm sure you can appreciate users running with low privilege and elevating only when necessary. :)

Comment: Yeah, except I was lying in my profile. Yes, I understand privilege elevation very well, and my singular contact with Windows 6/7 is on my kid's machine which has to boot Windows occasionally because she's locked into iTunes. I'll admit that I've not looked hard for UAC control, but I don't think I should have to. Even allegedly smart companies are still making the same stupid mistake http://flotsamand.blogspot.com/2010/06/noisy-warnings-they-should-know-better.html And regarding my allusions, most of the people I call friends don't get my so-called sense of humor, either; sorry. peace out.